# configure cdn in applicationResources.groovy

Tags: grails

I'm not clear on how to configure my applicationResources.groovy to use CDN for resources.  My file looks like:

```
    core {
        dependsOn 'jquery'

//        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        resource url:'http://localhost/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js'
        resource url:'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        resource url:'http://localhost/js/modernizr.js'
        resource url:'http://localhost/js/bootbox.min.js'
        resource url:'http://localhost/js/flatui-checkbox.js'
        resource url:'http://localhost/js/flatui-radio.js'
        resource url:'http://localhost/js/jquery.tagsinput.js'
        resource url:'http://localhost/js/jquery.placeholder.js'
        resource url:'http://localhost/js/util.js'
        resource url:'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css', disposition: 'head'
        resource url:'http://localhost/css/flat-ui.css', disposition: 'head'
        resource url:'http://localhost/css/base.css', disposition: 'head'
    }
```

Is there a place I can set http:// localhost one time instead of listing it over and over for each resource?  My dev environment uses localhost, but production will use a cdn.

Something like:

```
myCDN=http://amazons3.com

resource url:???/js/myfile01.js
resource url:???/js/myfile02.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, The config files are .groovy and should be processed just like any other code in the application.

To do so, just put in your config closure:

```
def myCDN='http://amazons3.com'

resource url: myCDN + '/js/myfile01.js'
resource url: myCDN + '/js/myfile02.js'
```

Good luck with it.